# How do I redirect someone from one action to another in ASP.NET MVC when an action has completed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

In my webapp (work in progress) I now try to allow new customers register to my webapp. I am deploying in Azure btw.

The idea I am working on:

**www.[mysite].com/Register**

This register page allows the "new" user to register his a new tenant.

**customer.[mysite].com/Register**

This pretty much looks as follows in code

```
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        var url = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];
        var tenantNameParser = new TenantNameParser(url);

        if (!TenantRepository.Exists(tenantNameParser.TenantName))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("NewCustomer");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

In the above snippet I check if tenant exists, if not, redirect to new customer.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewCustomer(Customer model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var tenant = new Tenant
                {
                    Name = model.TenantName,
                    Guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                };

            TenantRepository.Add(tenant);
            // TODO create a new user new tenant repository to do this stuff as 1 atomic action

            if (!UserRepository.Exists(model.AccountableEmailAddress))
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                var createStatus = MembershipService.CreateUser(
                    model.AccountableUser,
                    model.Password,
                    model.AccountableEmailAddress);

                if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                {
                    FormsService.SignIn(model.AccountableUser, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }

                throw new Exception("crappy implemenation, improve");
            }
            FormsService.SignIn(model.AccountableUser, false);

            // TODO figure out how to redirect to tenant.site.com
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

The code above creates a new customer, and in the end my //todo is what this question is about. How to redirect to an URL that includes the actual tenant in the form of tenant.domain.com?

I don't know if this "way of handling tenants" is a bad practice, if so please feel free to say so.

Question: How to redirect to a tenant URL ([tenantname.[mysite].com/Index/Home). Something like:
Redirect("tenantname", "Index", "Home") would be great, but of course doesn't exist. I google'd it for a bit, but didn't run into helpful links (that's mainly the reason why I think I am designing "the wrong thing").

Advice would be awesome! Thx a lot for your considerations in advance!

If I need to rephrase stuff because it's unclear what I ask for then please let me know.

Comment: Your second question is appropriate; if you show some code and expand on what you've got. The first question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Again, "Advice" and "bad practices vs. Good practices" are not the types of questions to ask on Stack Overflow. Just so it isn't closed, I recommend editing that out and narrow your question down to the actual technical problem you face.

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't realize that. I am afraid we both edited the post (or at least somebody did). Hopefully I didn't undo changes. I now ask specifically for the technical help, and pray that experienced folks will still tell me if I am doing something backwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just my 2 cents, please correct me if it's wrong.

My understanding is, you cannot control the tenant name in [tenant name].yoursite.com in your code, as it's out of the scope of ASP.NET MVC. It's a CNAME of the domain yoursite.com. So some thoughts from my end below.

1. I guess you need a program-able domain provider, which means you can create CNAME from your code. Then when a new customer registered, the actual URL might be yoursite.com/[tenant name]/. Then you map it to a new CNAME [tenant name].yoursite.com.
2. I'm not sure an URL Rewrite can help you. Which means you create a new rule and if the incoming URL was [tenant name].yoursite.com, you map it to yoursite.com/[tenant name]/

Comment: I think this puts me in the right direction. I will look into this this evening and report back here. I will leave the question open for today, maybe somebody else can point me to some examples. Thx so far!

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, you need to look at [Domain Routing](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx) for ASP .NET MVC.

Comment: Link only answers are not preferred, because if the link dies, then this answer becomes useless for future visitors.

Comment: funny, was browsing around and ended up on the link you already gave. that icw cname is the solution. sorry for the late accept, didn't look close enough yesterday.

Comment: @Haxx no problem, I'm glad you found what you were looking for.